# Grid inline editor - unable to get the edited column values in addCommitHandler method of grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

When I'm trying to click `save` after the edited the column cell with new user name, I'm not able to get the new cell value, instead I'm getting the old value.

```
grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(new FieldGroup.CommitHandler() 
{
    @Override
    public void preCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) throws     
    FieldGroup.CommitException {
        BeanItem item = (BeanItem)  
        commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource();
       User user= (User) item.getBean();
       user.getName();//getting the old value instead the new column value
     }
}
```

I have used the BeanItemContainer like below:

```
BeanItemContainer<User> container = new BeanItemContainer<User>(User.class);
grid.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

Answer (score 4):

`preCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent)` is called **before** the commit. So the BeanItem's bean (User) contains the old values (the new values were not yet committed into the bean). Therefore `getName()` returns the old value.

If you want to access the new value you have to use `postCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent)` which is called **after** the commit.

```
grid.getEditorFieldGroup().addCommitHandler(new FieldGroup.CommitHandler() {
            @Override
            public void preCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) {
                BeanItem item = (BeanItem)
                        commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource();
                User user = (User) item.getBean();
                String name = user.getName(); // old value
                System.out.println(name);
            }

            @Override
            public void postCommit(FieldGroup.CommitEvent commitEvent) {
                BeanItem item = (BeanItem)
                        commitEvent.getFieldBinder().getItemDataSource();
                User user = (User) item.getBean();
                String name = user.getName(); // new value
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @codinghaus!.

Answer (score 0):

We can able to fetch the new value in the preCommit() method itself by the following code,

```
TextField nameField = (TextField) grid.getColumn("name").getEditorField();
nameField .getValue(); // new name
```